# What am I doing wrong on "Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jwt, hmac

I am stuck with generating a JWT. When I run the code below I get "NiQPVTQSv3OyW5mFH27_wWMbTp1wOTScYP468rHddbQ" as *encodedSignature* which fails with the server.

The expected *encodedSignature* is "61Wp2O45amZBgdRzWwqdnRBQC2c9Fi7KMv8RLvH1vks". (It is from the working code in python).

According to the [google reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue,-key), two inputs for **Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature()** need to be either byte[], byte[] or string, string. Aren't my inputs matching in terms of type?

```js
function resecret(s) {

  var bin_secret = "";
  var duo = ""
  var new_secret_array = [];
  var j = 0;
  var len=s.length;
  var element = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    duo = s.charAt(i) + s.charAt(i+1);
    element = parseInt(duo, 16);
    bin_secret = bin_secret + element;
    new_secret_array[j] = element;
    j++;
    i++;
  }
  return new_secret_array;
}

function theProblem() {
    var claim = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI0MjM4NmZiMGFjMTI1YjQ0MzFiMTI5ZTMzNDBhOGIxOSIsImlhdCI6MTU4ODI1MzU3NywibmJmIjoxNTg4MjUzNTc3LCJleHAiOjE1ODgyNTQxNzcsImhvc3QiOiJodHRwczovL3NvbWV3aGVyZS5zb21lSG9zdC5jb20iLCJwYXRoIjoiL3NvbWUvcGF0aCIsIm1ldGhvZCI6IkdFVCJ9";
    var client_secret = "a1a2a3";
    var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(claim, resecret(client_secret));
    var encodedSignature = base64Encode(signature);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your python code?

Comment: The syntax is `computeHmacSha256Signature(value, key)`. So if you get the wrong output, it means you use the wrong key.

Comment: @ziganotschka, do you know if the data type of the claim and resecret(client_secret) are same?

Comment: @TheMaster I imported jwt then used `jwt.encode(payload, client_secret, algorithm="HS256")`. When calling jwt.encode, I do convert the client secret where `client_secret = binascii.unhexlify("a1a2a3")`

Comment: Your function `function resecret(s)` return an array, while `computeHmacSha256Signature` expects a string.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show working python code. `jwt.encode()` will always return `header.payload.signature`. The result you claim that this code results in `61Wp2O45amZBgdRzWwqdnRBQC2c9Fi7KMv8RLvH1vks` is impossible.

Comment: @ziganotschka - Are you indicating claim being a string?

Comment: @TheMaster - `61Wp2O45amZBgdRzWwqdnRBQC2c9Fi7KMv8RLvH1vks` is the signature portion (after the second dot)

Comment: Base64 should be done before hmac